# How to load content from external page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-load

Is it possible to load content from an external page (not relative) into div using jquery?
I mean here by external page is another web application like for example: http://www.yahoo.com
There is the code:

```
$("#externalContent").load("http://www.yahoo.com", function () {
    alert("loading finish");
});
```

when I use firebug I got this result:
[Firebug result http://devville.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/jQuery-LoadExternalContent.png](http://devville.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/jQuery-LoadExternalContent.png)

you see here, i highlighted the response code, it's 200 which means OK, but still no content loaded.
DOES anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a standard security context, you cannot access data on a remote URI without using a trick such as JSON-P or proxying the data through your own server. The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) gets in the way.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate 'cross-domain', the following table gives the overview of typical outcomes for checks against the URL "http://www.example.com/dir/page.html".
[alt text http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/7650/crossdomain.gif](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/7650/crossdomain.gif)

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

status==200 would just mean that the url exists...

Answer (score 1):

You can send a request to your script on the same domain that will grab yahoo.com content on a server side (not client side) and return it to you.

Comment: This could be a solution but I will use iframe rather than this method. Thank you all guys